# Reference request: concave/convex envelope

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

I'm seeking the references concerning on the regularity analysis of concave envelopes, *i.e.* given some measurable function $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ that is bounded from above ($d=1$ or $d\ge 1$), denote by $f_{\#}$ its concave envelope, *i.e.*

1. $f_{\#}:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ is concave and $f_{\#}\ge f$;
2. For any concave function $g:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ s.t. $g\ge f$, one has $g\ge f_{\#}$.

Assume that $d=1$. I'm mainly interested in the boundedness of the (left/right) derivative $f_{\#}'$. Under what kind of conditions on $f$, we can show that $f_{\#}'$ is uniformly bounded? Any related reference is welcome! Thanks a  lot!

Comment: It depends very much on each particular $f$. On $\mathbb{R}$ we should first require that concave envelope exists: the graph of $f$ should be below a linear function $f(x)\leq Ax+B$. Besides, we should require $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz in order to expect that  the envelope is uniformly Lipschitz. I believe these 2 conditions  will be also sufficient.

Comment: The paper: 
"The Dirichlet Problem for the Degenerate Monge--Amp\`ere equation", L. Caffarelli, L. Nirenberg, J. Spruck, 
studies regularity properties of the concave envelopes for  obstacles $f$ given on the boundary of a convex set.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Paata Ivanisvili, BD. and Dirk for their reply and I'd like to summarize what I'm thinking about this issue. I claim that it is not an answer.

Assume that **$f$ is bounded from above and $L-$Lipschitz**. To simplify assume further $d=1$ and $f_{\#}$ is differentiable. Then one has $\|f_{\#}'\|\le L$. If not, assume that there exists $x_0$ s.t. $f_{\#}'(x_0)=M>L$, then $f_{\#}'(x)\ge M>L$ for all $x\le x_0$, and thus

$$\limsup_{x\to-\infty}\big(f_{\#}(x)-f(x)\big)~~=~~-\infty.$$

If otherwise there exists $x_0$ s.t. $f_{\#}'(x_0)<-L$, one has as well

$$\limsup_{x\to+\infty}\big(f_{\#}(x)-f(x)\big)~~=~~-\infty.$$

These two situations contradict the definition of $f_{\#}$.

**I look forward to the further analysis on the regularity of $f_{\#}$, once $f$ is supposed bo be very "nice"**. Finally, I find the following paper which may be useful for who is also interested in this issue:

https://people.math.ethz.ch/~afigalli/papers/Optimal%20regularity%20of%20the%20convex%20envelope.pdf

Comment: Actually, the Caferelli et al paper is available via researchgate (google-scholar it and check "all 4 versions").

Answer (score 1):

I think the Benson's paper can be a good reference.

You can find it here:

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:COAP.0000004976.52180.7f